# Capture and store object detection

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, object-detection

I am doing an object detection model to detect my custom objects which are streetlight and the label on the streetlight using yolov3.

So here's my question, I want my model to detect the label of the streetlight by drawing bounding boxes around it. After drawing the bounding boxes, I want the model to capture the image inside the bounding box and store it for OCR which is for future steps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to crop the image out of the bounded box after you compare the class/object, see the below post for the OCR setup- https://stackabuse.com/pytesseract-simple-python-optical-character-recognition/